# How to add a frontend asset from a git repo/npm project to a rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stylesheet, assets

I want to contribute to an open source project written in `rails` with some frontend web stuff, that depends on an asset, which I have on an external `git` repository. So I would like to add the asset dependency from the `git` link and just add my code to the frontend.

I do not know much about `rails`, especially asset managements, but that the `css` and `js` files are all in the manifest files, and come seemingly from some ruby gems, which include the `css` and `js` assets then.

So is there a good way to add an asset to my rails manifest file/assets without having it as a ruby gem, just from a git repo?

Thank you so much for help and pardon my rails illiteracy :S

Comment: So you have this repository that you want to download and add its css and js files to your rails project?

Comment: Rigth, but preferably just by adding the repo link and let rails do the downloading :) Just as you you would add a dependency in your `package.json` in npm with `"package-name": "git+https://repo.url/link.git",` :)

Comment: Well if your repo doesn't contain a valid Gem or npm package. then I don't think that  you will be able to add it through your repo link, you will have to download the assets and add them locally (css and js files)

Comment: So how do I it with a npm package if you mentioned it :)

Comment: Because yes, my project is a npm package :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to add just a `.gemspec` to my `npm` repo, move my `js` and `css` to the `vendor/assets` folder, all in a dedicated "gemfile branch"

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'asset-name'
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.date        = '2020-05-30'
  s.summary     = "What my package does."
  s.description = ""
  s.files       = [
        "vendor/assets/javascripts/app.min.js",
        "vendor/assets/stylesheets/app.css"
  ]
  s.license       = 'MIT'
end
```

and then added the repo with it`s branch to the rail projects`Gemfile` like this:

`gem "asset-name", :git => "git://github.com/user/repo.git", :branch => "ruby-gem"`